# Travelling to Canada

Tags: visas, canada, scams

It has been pointed out to me that a female wanting to visit a male friend in Canada has to have at least $3,600.00 Canadian funds for a maximum visit of 90 days, plus they have to get a visitors visa from the federal migration service and now the bank and bailiff department can stop a person from leaving or getting their visa if they have a mortgage. what is happening to our world.
Could anyone knowing that could clarify this I would appreciate.
Thanks , Ray.

Comment: Who has pointed this out to you? A female whom you have met on the internet?

Comment: Keep your money in your wallet. Preferably attach a chain to the wallet. Like [this](https://www.hottopic.com/product/blackcraft-baphomet-logo-tri-fold-chain-wallet-hot-topic-exclusive/11301920.html?mr:trackingCode=230B70CA-034A-E811-80F9-0050569428E8&mr:referralID=NA&mr:device=c&mr:adType=plaonline&mr:ad=119392120466&mr:keyword=&mr:match=&mr:tid=pla-439078476860&mr:ploc=9007877&mr:iloc=&mr:store=&mr:filter=439078476860&CM_MMC=CSE-_-GGL-_-PLA-_-1_9999W1_CSE_GGL_Everything_Desktop_11301920&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2f7bBRDVARIsAAwYBBs2wFKB2GEJo2RAoe2JKYr498czAUVEd2lcqSTOWEZrAmkEDssa8RwaAqckEALw_wcB)

Comment: Disagree with the closure. Not the same question, not necessarily the same answer.

Answer (score 10):

**What you have been told is completely wrong.**

Having different conditions for visiting Canada that depend on your gender, or the gender of the person you are visiting, would be a violation of the Canadian constitution.

There is no minimum amount of money you have to have in Canadian funds to visit Canada. Many people visit Canada every day with no Canadian funds at all. They change money when they get here, or use credit cards. There is no minimum amount of money you need to get a Canadian visa.

Many people do need a visa to visit Canada, but others do not. It depends mainly on your nationality and the purpose of your visit. Having a mortgage will not prevent you getting a visa to Canada. Here are general instructions for [what you need to do to visit Canada.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp)

There is no department in Canada that will prevent you leaving Canada unless you are wanted for a crime. There is no such government department in Canada as the 'bank' or 'bailiff' department. No bank or bailiff has any power to prevent anyone leaving Canada.

**If this is someone telling you this who you have never met in person, who you believe to be in a romantic relationship with you, and wants money so she can come visit you, I'm sorry but you are being scammed.** That is what is happening to our world. Send them no money and break off the relationship.

Comment: The last paragraph here deserves more emphasis than the gods of typography will allow.

Comment: @R.D.Harrison In the unlikely event you need any further convincing that you’re being scammed, why not read up on the requirements yourself http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp